# How to configure 3G/4G dongle in macos 64bit version?

Tags: macos, network, catalina, driver, 64-bit

I have faced this problem of not able to connect to 3G/4G dongles, currently the Huawei E3372 one. Was using Mobile Partner app & since the 64bit upgrade it has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a quick work around using the default "Network" option.
I am using Airtel 4G & Huawei E3372 dongle.
Below are the steps followed:
 1. Open System Preferences > Network

- Configure adapter HuaweiMobile-
- Configuration: Default
- Telephone Number: *99#

  2. In the Advanced pane:
- Vendor: Generic Model: GPRS (GSM/3G)
- APN: Default (check for APN through your provided for other services)
- CID: 1

Select "Show Modem in status bar" for easy toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Updated (x64 version) driver for Huawei E3372 with `stick` firmware, tested on Mac OS Catalina: https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=582284&st=51900#entry90299563

Installing `MobileConnectDriver.pkg` is enough for connecting using [system dialing feature](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2019/04/17/huawei-e3372-macos/#connecting-to-the-internet-on-mac-os).

Answer (score -2):

All,

Solution found and please see in the Link.

See full video for Better understanding":

https://youtu.be/oNRuZm2IB5A